# Webpack: cannot load slick plugin having global jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, slick.js

I'm trying to load [slick plugin](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) with [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) version 2.6.1., without success so far.

I need to have jquery loaded as a global variable and version 2.2.4 (because I have other old plugins to manage), so I've set *ProvidePlugin* in my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: { filename: './src/js/main.js' },
  output: { filename: './dist/js/bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery'
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv) }
    })
  ]
};
```

My **main.js** file is the following:

```
import 'slick-carousel';
console.log('jquery version: ', $.fn.jquery);
console.log($.fn.slick);
```

**bundle.js** file is produced by webpack with the following log:

```
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 1490ms
                  Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    ./dist/js/bundle.js  616 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  filename
./dist/js/bundle.js.map  794 kB       0  [emitted]         filename
   [0] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 258 kB {0} [built]
   [1] ./~/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js 84.3 kB {0} [built]
   [2] ./src/js/main.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
   [3] ./~/slick-carousel/~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 268 kB {0} [built]
```

jQuery is loaded twice: the first in the global environment, version 2.2.4 and the second one is version 3.2.1 (version too recent for me, that I don't want) included as dependency by slick, I guess.

Loading it into an html page, I get in the browser dev tools the following logs:

```
jquery version: 2.2.4
undefined
```

So, jquery is correctly loaded but slick is not.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found solution which works for me:

1. add to `js` file:

   ```
   import $ from 'jquery';
   import 'slick-carousel';
   ```
2. add to `scss` file:

   ```
   $slick-font-path: "/node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/" !default;
   $slick-font-family: "slick" !default;
   $slick-loader-path: "/node_modules/slick-carousel/slick-carousel/slick/" !default;
   $slick-arrow-color: black !default;
   @import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss"; 
   @import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss";
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my **package.json**: I had *slick-carousel* inside the **dependencies** property and *jquery* inside **devDependencies** instead.

Moving *jquery* inside dependencies solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using webpack 5.74 i added a new rules like so after install npm install expose-loader

```
               {
                    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: {
                        exposes: ['jQuery', '$']
                    },
                }
```

and it worked like a charm.